# Using the requirejs shimConfig to load jQuery plugin

Tags: javascript, jquery, requirejs, shim

This code uses the `requirejs.shimConfig` to load the jQuery.mCustomScrollbar plugin:

```
requirejs.config({
  baseUrl:'scripts',
  paths:{
    async:'lib/plugins/async',
    domReady:'lib/plugins/domReady',
    jquery:"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min", 
    "jquery.mCustomScrollbar":"lib/plugins/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min"  
  },
  shim:{
        "jquery.mCustomScrollbar":{
           deps:['jquery'],
           exports:'jQuery.fn.mCustomScrollbar'
          }
       }
});
```

However the Chrome console shows that `requirejs` tries to load the file from the `baseUrl`:

```
 GET http://localhost:8180/GoogleMapErpProject/scripts/jQuery.mCustomScrollbar.js 404   (Not Found) require.js:34
 Uncaught Error: Script error for: jQuery.mCustomScrollbar
 http://requirejs.org/docs/errors.html#scripterror
```

## EDIT:

I have found an unsatisfactory solution to the issue:

```
  requirejs.config({
baseUrl:'scripts',
paths:{
    async:'lib/plugins/async',
    domReady:'lib/plugins/domReady',
    jquery:"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min",
    plugins:"lib/plugins"   
},
shim:{
    "jquery":{
        exports:"jQuery"
    },
    "plugins/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min":{
        deps:['jquery'],
        exports:'jQuery.fn.mCustomScrollbar'
    }
   }
});
```

Why would it not work when I specified a path in the `paths` and used that path in the `shimConfig`?

Answer (score 0):

from require.js documentation,

> **[baseUrl](http://requirejs.org/docs/api.html#config-baseUrl)**: the root path to use for all module lookups. So in the above
>   example, "my/module"'s script tag will have a
>   src="/another/path/my/module.js". baseUrl is not used when loading
>   plain .js files (indicated by a dependency string starting with a
>   slash, has a protocol, or ends in .js), those strings are used as-is,
>   so a.js and b.js will be loaded from the same directory as the HTML
>   page that contains the above snippet.

Hence paths should/can be like this:

```
paths:{
    async:'lib/plugins/async',
    domReady:'lib/plugins/domReady',
    jquery:"http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min", 
    "jquery.mCustomScrollbar":"/lib/plugins/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min"  
  },
```

or

```
paths:{
    ...
    "jquery.mCustomScrollbar":"./lib/plugins/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min"  
  },
```

or

```
paths:{
    ... 
    "jquery.mCustomScrollbar":"lib/plugins/jquery.mCustomScrollbar.concat.min.js"  
  },
```

if you dont want it to get loaded from baseUrl.

Comment: the value I have provided for `jQuery.mCustomScrollbar` is relative to the `baseUrl`.Also check the solution I posted,this seems to work but it will not allow me to do a paths fallback if I wanted to.